# Track users from website to ios app install

Tags: analytics

I have affiliate websites linking to my ios app. I would like to track this and be able to know where each user was referred from.

What is the best way to do this? I am thinking of the following:

1. Include a javascript on each affiliate website that displays a Smart App Banner and records the visitor IP when viewed through an iPhone
2. When an app is installed, compare the user's IP to the IPs recorded through the javascript. Assume it is the same user if same IP within a 15 minute timeframe.

This is not perfect (as several users might have the same IP address). Are there any better ways?

Comment: you can find this link useful on the [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)

Comment: as far as I've understood, there's no way to send data from the smart app banner to the app when the app is not installed on the user's device... so it doesn't seem to solve my problem

Comment: @David Have you found any way to do this? Does this is achievable by google analytics?